# Getting errors on SPFx hello world web part in SharePoint 2016 referencing a "strings" file

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I am trying to get a hello world web part to work in SharePoint 2016.

I believe the SharePoint server has Feature Pack 2 installed as I see that KB4484255 (version 16.0.4966.100) shows as installed which is the February 2020 update.

[image]

My understanding is that I need KB4092459 (version 16.0.474.1000), but that the more recent update above is a cumulative update.  However, I'm not certain of that, so maybe that's where I have things wrong.

My dev environment looks like:

- node v6.10.3 (using nvm)
- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.1.0 (globally installed)
- npm@3.10.10 (globally installed)
- yo@1.8.5 (globally installed)

I chose no JavaScript framework and just used the code out of the box.  The web part works in the workbench. I made no code changes after running the Yeoman generator other than updating the write-manifests.json file to have a URL to my cdnBasePath set to an Azure container URL.  I also updated deploy-azure-storage.json, but that doesn't appear to be working as I manually copied the resulting dist files to the container.  The dist files are:

- 7be2dcde-e1b3-4643-804f-26a2458ca04f.manifest.json
- hello-world.bundle.js
- hello-world.bundle.js.map

I did a "bundle --ship" and "package-solution --ship".  And uploaded the sppkg file to my SP2016 app catalog.  It showed Yes for Enabled, Valid App Package, and Deployed in the app catalog.

I added the app to my test site. It took several minutes for that to complete.  I tried manually running the App Installation Service timer job from Central Admin hoping it would help (I don't know if it did).

I created a test page and tried to add the web part.  I looked for the web part under the "Under Development" category and it was not there.  A couple of hours later I deployed a totally different hello world web part (different name and description - created via the Yeoman generator) and then this web part finally showed up in the "Under Development" category.  I don't know if one triggered the other.

Upon adding the web part to the page I get an error:

> ***ERROR MESSAGE:
> ***Failed to load component "7be2dcde-e1b3-4643-804f-26a2458ca04f" (HelloWorldWebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load URL
> 'https://.blob.core.windows.net/helloworld-webpart/helloworld-webpart-helloworldstrings_en-us_536e65149b0acf4d52c0043073b9fc59.js'
> for resource 'helloWorldStrings' in component
> '7be2dcde-e1b3-4643-804f-26a2458ca04f' (HelloWorldWebPart). There was
> a network problem. This may be a problem with a HTTPS certificate.
> Make sure you have the right certificate.

I don't have a helloworld-webpart-helloworldstrings_en-us_536e65149b0acf4d52c0043073b9fc59.js file in my dist folder.  Any idea how I should generate it or otherwise fix this issue?

UPDATE:

I have also tried the same thing using the following for my dev environment:

- node v8.17.0 (using nvm)
- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.9.1 (globally installed)
- npm@3.10.10 (globally installed)
- windows-build-tools@5.2.2 (globally installed)
- yo@1.8.5 (globally installed)

I don't know if the build tools are required.  I get the same error as my first environment further above looking for a strings file.

Comment: I think the problem is how it is trying to download the files from Azure blob storage.  I made sure the container was publicly accessible, but even if I remove the 3 dist files from the Azure blob container, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my main problem was I needed to copy files from my temp\deploy folder to my Azure container instead of files from my dist folder.

I also used an Azure CDN as described [here](https://tutorialsinhand.com/tutorials/sharepoint-framework-spfx-tutorial/sharepoint-framework-webparts/using-azure-storage-account-cdn-in-spfx.aspx), but I don't know if that was necessary.